# Turn "on the fly" pages of a word document to a paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word, docx, xceed

I have a set of docx files autogenerated from a pdf set

I further want to turn these documents to a specific json structures for future use

And I need indexed paragraphs and pages so that they match, meaning

| index | object |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | pg 1 |
| 2 | paragaraph 1 |
| 3 | paragraph 2 |
| 4 | pg 2 |
| 5 | paragraph 3 |

I use free Xceed.DocX lib and it allows to get docx paragraph as an ordered list and so it does deliver pages (they are treated as a paragraph in most cases).

Sometimes however it does not. Now I have the case when page numbers are calculated "on the fly" when opening in word and I'm searching for an option to somehow auto add an extra paragraph (it can be tiny, mb 1px font size) on each page which will contain just current page number.

I think this should be possible with Word automation, please let me know if you have any idea

Comment: Word page numbers are *always* calculated "on the fly", because Word optimises the page layout to suit the active printer. Change printers (or even printer drivers) and the pagination is liable to change. And, especially in documents subject to ongoing editing, there is no reliable way of inserting the kind of content you want into the document body such that you can ensure there will always be exactly one such item on each and every page.

Comment: @macropod I got pdf as a starting point and page numbers "hardcoded" in it. Turning them to docx via online tools bring these numbers to be paragraphs (in most cases). Anyway found a tool that does insert page paragraphs in my case. Thanks for the feedback and closing the question

Comment: What your PDF contains is irrelevant. As I already told you, Word optimises the page layout to suit the active printer - and that is liable to result in the pagination changing. In other words, your 'hardcoded' page #s could end up on different pages to what they were in the PDF. You *cannot* insert anything into the document body that guarantees the correct page # will appear there on every page. A simple PAGE field in the header or footer can do that, however.

Comment: @macropod you know better than me what is relevant and what is not in my project. Ok, that happens

Answer (score 0):

I got PDF as a starting point and page numbers "hardcoded" in it. Turning them to DOCX via online tools bring these numbers to be paragraphs (in most cases). Anyway found a tool that does insert page paragraphs in my case.

The tool is: https://pdf2docx.com/